# Open contextmenu programmatically

Tags: svg, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a svg element on top of the viewer canvas created with snap.svg, so I can draw nametags for elements on this svg layer. After I create the svg layer the viewer reacts to left clicks normally, but doesn't open the context menu anymore. How to open the context menu programmatically? I can catch the click event with jQuery and get the x and y location.

```
$("#svg-canvas").contextmenu(function (e) {
  console.log('x: ' + e.screenX + ' y: ' + e.screenY);
});
```

I tried also changing the z-index of .menu and the svg layer, but if the svg layer is on top and shows the svg elements, it does not open the context menu with right click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the Viewer 2.11 source code and this seems to work.

```
viewer.contextMenu.show(event);
```